# Mat element bulk modification : negative to 0, positive to 1

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have a matrix of negative and positive integers. I want to set negative elements to 0 and positive elements to 1. 
I do not want to set each element individually.

Is there any function/combination of functions in OpenCv that can perform this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: (Edited for typos in title.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the function [threshhold](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold). Also, [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) explains how to get a binary image by applying a fixed-level threshold to each array element.

```
cv::Mat source_array, binary_output;
cv::threshold(source_array, binary_output, 0, 1, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is called [thresholding](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold). The answer depends on what language you're using. Below are a few examples.

## C++

```
cv::threshold(m, m, 0, 1, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

## C

```
cvThreshold(m, m, 0, 1, THRESH_BINARY);
```

## Python (numpy, cv2)

```
m = m > 0
```

## Python (cv)

```
cv.Threshold(m, m, 0, 1, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)
```